# Javascript if googlemap lat long value is empty hide div

Tags: javascript

Hi Hope someone can help me out on this

I have a map with dynamic data from a Json file The datafields from json are [[LAT]] [[LONG]]

What I'm trying to do is that if there is no value send by the json file, the mapcontainer div has to close. What I have so far isn't working.

here the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.892374,5.992003);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                streetViewControl: true,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            if (latlng !== "50.892374" , "5.992003000000068"){
            alert(latlng)
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            }
            else{
            alert("hide mapcontainer div")
            document.getElementById("mapcontainer").style.visibility = 'none';
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Problem is that latlng, whatever I do, is never equal to the value I gave in my example.

This is the div I want to close:

```
  <div class="mapcontainer" id="mapcontainer">
  <div class="themap">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

In my actual work latlng would look like this:
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng([[LAT]],[[LONG]]);

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

This test will never work:
if (latlng !== "50.892374" , "5.992003000000068"){

you are comparing a google.maps.LatLng object against a pair of strings; I would expect you to get a javascript error on that.

The [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) has an equals method that allows you to compare it against another google.maps.LatLng, but I would suggest a distance comparison (floating point numbers are almost never equal) using the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) (check to see if the 2 LatLng objects are "close" enough to be the same)

Comment: Hi geocodezip, Thanks for helping me out with my question. I don't completely understand but maybe you have an alterative route to achieve my goal. So I just want to hide the mapcontainer if no values are given for latlng.

Comment: Your new question " I just want to hide the mapcontainer if no values are given", doesn't have anything to do with the Google Maps API or Google Maps, it is a general dynamic HTML question.  Maybe edit the question and its tags (or create a new one) to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks I did that but can you help me with this question?